# Deploy contract to Kovan with brownie and infura

Tags: infura, kovan, brownie

I'm trying to simply deploy a smart contract in Kovan network, i've used the export of the ID using `export WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID=xxxx` but i'm getting this error

```
ValueError: The method eth_sendTransaction does not exist/is not available
```

Taking a look into infura documentation, that method is not avaible. What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem was in `brownie-config.yaml` file, where i set the deployer address as `cmd_settings / unlock`. After removing the address from there, the deployment went OK. I guess i misunderstood the `unlock` feature!

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this from the Infura community forums: https://community.infura.io/t/the-method-eth-sendtransaction-does-not-exist-is-not-available/1537